# Exclude IPs from IP list that are from Russia

Tags: bash, sed, lookup, geoip

Which command in Bash should I use to exclude all IPs that are from Russia from an IP list?

I had in mind maybe with the help of `geoiplookup`. What I would really like to have as result;

- original-IP-list.txt
- IP-list-excluding-IPs-from-Russia.txt

Comment: How is the list formatted?

Comment: 1 IP per line: 1.2.3.4

Answer (score 2):

You may find the list of Russian IPs in the webpage
[Russian Federation IP Address Ranges](https://lite.ip2location.com/russian-federation-ip-address-ranges).
The list currently contains 8381 ranges which makes assigned
45,626,826 IP addresses.

If you would rather have a programming solution, you may use the website `ipinfo.io`,
free for 1000 requests/day:

```
curl ipinfo.io/23.66.166.151
```

You may alternatively use `ifconfig.me` or `ipstack.com`, each with its own
free and paid plans.

Comment: This might be useful in some case but my IP list is around 80k if not more; I thought the best solution was with something like 'cat ./ip_list.txt | xargs -n 1 geoiplookup { } | grep "RU" > exclude.Russia_IPs.txt' but that's not the correct syntax to fulfill my needs... ;/

Comment: I didn't recommend `geoiplookup` because there are many negative reports for it. Good that it worked for you.

Comment: Download IP ranges from https://lite.ip2location.com/russian-federation-ip-address-ranges, trim them and create exclude.Russia_IPs.txt with this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681431/3776858

Answer (score 1):

For those who are searching for an answer like I was searching earlier;

```
while read -r ip; do gl=$(geoiplookup "$ip") || continue; case "$gl" in *': RU,'*) printf '%s\n' "$ip" ;; esac; done  <"$1"
```

enjoy!